# Ask for user credentials only after iPhone restarts/reboot

Tags: ios, iphone, restart

Is it possible to ask user for user credentials only when app launched first time **after every restart/reboot** of iPhone?
Like iOS asks for passcode after restarting iPhone.

Basically I want to take password from user while registering to app and save it on device.
Then each and every time he/she launches app, use that saved credentials to login.
But as he/she restarts/reboots iPhone and launches app for first time then only ask for credentials.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Save status of login in user default. And check on every launch option of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions

Comment: I want to ask for credentials only after device restarted, not every time app launched